# Websphere Management Jython & JMX

Tags: java, websphere

I am doing some custom management programs with Websphere. 
I am using AdminClient to connect with WebSphere server.

However, being new to the WebSphere world. I am confused with few parts.

Currently, I am using JMX apis to manage application. 
I am using AppManagement to perform application related operations. That is working smoothly.

- However, I am facing issues for installing WAR files. There's no API for installing WAR. It works for EAR.
- Also, I am not getting any classes to manage server features like start, create application servers, nodes.

**Where can I find it ?** Any documentation is welcome.

If there are no API, is it a good idea to call WSAdmin scripts from java code ?

Also, is there any documentation available to map the WSAdmin script or jython code to Java code ?

It's really frustrating due to the lack of proper documentation in java. (May be I am unable to find at right places)

Answer (score 0):

Stick to EAR, it has more info (e.g. context root) that is needed

chose wsadmin or java, not both

jython/jacl examples are well documented

See if these help

http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2009/02/15/automating-websphere-using-jmx/

http://www.websphereusergroup.org/steverobinson/blog/2013/01/30/connecting_jmx_clients_to_a_secure_websphere_server

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html

Comment: I can't restrict user from installing only EAR. Application can be WAR, EAR or any other.

Also, I am currently using JAVA APIs for application management. 

E.g. AppManagementProxy.startApplication(appName, target, prefs,
     null);

However, I couldn't find APIs for server management something like server.stop()

As long as monitoring information is concerned, I am able to get the information from MBeans.

However, for management, I am using 
AdminClient.invoke(server, "stop", null, null);

That works fine, but I am not sure if that is a right approach. 

Appreciate any advice on this.